# Configuring a carousel view that shows multiple elements at once [VanillaJS]

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

By multiple elements at once, I mean a carousel view like this one: 
[image]

When there is only **one element being shown at any time**, I used the following equation to calculate the translation limit (the point at which the carousel should reset to its original position):
`limit = (number of elements * width of one element) - (width of one element * number of elements visible at any one time)`
This equation still works with multiple elements, but I don't know how to dynamically calculate the **number of elements visible at any time**, when there is a change in screen size.
Here is my current code:

```js
    var num_featured = 6
    complete_width = 200+ 25*2
    const next_button_featured = document.querySelector('.actions.carousel.next')
    const carousel_featured = document.querySelector('.featured.carousel.inner')
    const carousel_featured_container = document.querySelector('.featured.carousel.outer')
    next_button_featured.addEventListener('click', () => {carousel_next_featured()})
    var translate_value  = 0
    function carousel_next_featured(){
        translate_value += complete_width
        if(translate_value >= complete_width*num_featured - complete_width*4 ){
            translate_value =0
        }
        carousel_featured.style.transform = 'translateX(-'+translate_value+'px)'
    }
```

```css
    .featured.outer.container{ margin: 50px 0; width: 100%;}
    .featured.inner.container{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .featured.title{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .featured.title h2{ font-size: 30px}
    
        .featured.carousel.outer{
        min-height: 200px;
        width: 90%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .featured.carousel.inner{
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 25px;
        transform: translateX(0);
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        width: min-content;
    }
    .featured.carousel.element.wrap{
        margin: 0 25px;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: black;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="featured outer container">
    <div class="featured inner container">
        <div class="title outer featured center">
            <h2 class="title">Featured</h2>
        </div>
        <button class="featured carousel actions next">></button>
        <div class="featured carousel outer">
            <div class="featured carousel inner">
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap" style="background-color: red">
                </div>
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap">
                </div>
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap">
                </div>
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap">
                </div>
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap">
                </div>
                <div class="featured carousel element wrap" style="background-color: green">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the carousel does not move to the right completely (the final element is green color).
This code seems to work only at a screen size where there are 4 elements visible at any time (screen width ~ 1550px).
**Possible solution**
Would it be possible to scrap the equation model and try to do something like this?
 `if distance between the right corner of the inner carousel and outer container = (0) => return to the zero position`
If so, how would I go about calculating the distance between the two corners?
Thanks.